# Node.js - Read a stream once a value has been found, then close

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, stream

So I have an idea to capture some data via a stream in a really large file. But I don't want to capture all of this data into memory. So what I would like to do is open a stream waiting until I find a match, Let's say an opening of a class `ClassName {`. Then close the stream and stop reading once the ending has been found `}`. Then return all of this data that has been captured.

I was thinking of using a transformer for this but I can't quite figure out how to wait until I find a certain string. I could put the current found data into memory and keep checking if it matches? But it doesn't seem quite right and I think there may be another solution which I haven't been able to find in the spec. I am happy to write the code, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Brackets can be nested, which one is the right on end the match?

Comment: I was going to do the first bracket that wasn't escaped. Since in the case I am using it for I will not be having nested brackets. The class was just an example to get the stream point across

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could create a single function that returns a promise.  Then, I would probably use the [Readline interface](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) to get the file line by line, scanning each line for the start and end of what I was looking for.  When you receive the end of what you're looking for, you can then call `.close()` on the file and then resolve the promise with the results that you've collected.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Just wondering whether it would be possible once the "opening" has been found, switching to a character by character read.

Comment: @mountaindrew - You can read character by character (just look at all the file reading methods in the `fs` module), but if you're doing it asynchronously, it's probably a lot more complicated that what I've suggested.  Once you have a line, you can just scan it character by character for whatever you're looking for.

Comment: @mountaindrew - You generally don't mix stream flowing with other types of reads so if you're using the line by line stream as I suggest, you wouldn't switch to reading one byte at a time in the middle.  Much easier to just take the next line and process the characters one at a time from the line.